# Copy row values to other rows with the same ID

Tags: excel, copy, rows

I have the following structure in an excel db:

```
ID   Variable1   Variable2
1     X          Y
2     X2         Y2
2
3     X3         Y3
4     X4         Y4
4
4
5     X5         Y5
```

I am searching for a formula (code?) that will copy the variable values of a given row to all other rows with the same ID. For example copy X4 and Y4 to all other rows containing 4 as ID.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes the the data is in columns A through C and requires the use of some helper columns:

- Populate D2 and down with the formula
  `=IF(B2="",INDEX(B$2:B$9,MATCH($A2,$A$2:$A$9,0)),"")`,
- With the range in column D still selected drag the fill handle across to
  populate column E,
- Populate F1 and down with `=A1`,
- Populate G1 and down with `=B1&D1`,
- With the range in column G still selected drag the fill handle across to
  populate column H.